# I want to get all players with a team name given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I will get team_name from previous page and then I want to show all the players with that team name in the browser. 
But it gives error and when I try to print variable `$players` it has only details of one player with that team name.
I think the result of query must be stored in some kind of 2-D array but I am not able to think the logic behind it.

Player Table has attributes

- player_name
- jearsy_no
- team_name
- phone_no
- dob

```
<?php 
 include('config/db_connect.php');
 if(isset($_GET['team_name'])) {
  $team_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['team_name']);
  $sql_players = "SELECT * FROM player WHERE team_name = '$team_name'";
  $result_players = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_players);
  $players = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_players);
  //print_r($players);
 }   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('templates/header.php'); ?>

  <?php foreach($players as $player) : ?> 
  <div class="container">
        <h6><?php echo htmlspecialchars($player['player_name']); ?></h6>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php include('templates/footer.php'); ?>
</html>
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'player_name'

And when I try to `print_r($players)` I get:

```
  Array ( [player_name] => Dwayn Miller 
          [jearsy_no] => 32 
          [team_name] => Team Australia 
          [dob] => 1998-12-11 
          [player_phone] => 4009871234 
        )
```

Comment: Try $player->player_name to reference the value

Comment: Note that your $players variable is not an array of players. Try $players['player_name'], [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) fetch a result row.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` only returns the first row, you have to iterate it to get all the rows. Try `while($player=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_players)){echo $player['player_name'];}`

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution that instead of

```
$players = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_players);
```

If I use `mysqli_fetch_all()` then I can get all players details with that team name

```
$players = mysqli_fetch_all($result_players, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $players = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_players);
```

That sets the perhaps unfortunately named `$players` to an associative array for *one* player row, as your `print_r` shows.

But here you treat `$players` as if you expect it to have *every* row.

```
  <?php foreach($players as $player) : ?>
```

You should be calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` once for each row, so you'll need to iterate over `$result_players` to pull each player row from the result set.

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.

You can simply watch the result coming out of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to decide whether yo `break` your loop.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php has a great example of how to do it with a `while` loop.   Essentially, it's:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

You could combine looping over each row, and outputting each row, by moving the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` call into the loop around the output:

```
  <?php while ($player = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_players) : ?> 
  <div class="container">
        <h6><?php echo htmlspecialchars($player['player_name']); ?></h6>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your code:

```
$players = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_players);
```

Then instead of looping `$players` loop on `$result_players`

```
<?php foreach($result_players as $player) : ?>
```

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns a single row from the result set. You could also get all records into an array using:

```
$players = mysqli_fetch_all($result_players, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

but if all you want to do is iterate over all the records from the result set, you can simply iterate on `$result_players`

**Warning:**
You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Together with prepared statements your code would look like this:

```
<?php
include 'config/db_connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['team_name'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM player WHERE team_name=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['team_name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result_players = $stmt->get_result();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('templates/header.php'); ?>

  <?php foreach($result_players as $player) : ?> 
  <div class="container">
        <h6><?php echo htmlspecialchars($player['player_name']); ?></h6>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php include('templates/footer.php'); ?>
</html>
```

Also don't forget to implement correct error reporting. See [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)